# Extend wizard in odoo module with super and not overwrite

Tags: python, module, odoo

I added some new fields in my module and at the moment I copied the whole api.onchange. see code:

```
` @api.onchange('company_id')
    def _onchange_company_id(self):
        for wizard in self:
            wizard.logo = wizard.company_id.logo
            wizard.report_header = wizard.company_id.report_header
            wizard.report_footer = wizard.company_id.report_footer
            # NEW: wizard.report_footer1 = wizard.company_id.report_footer1
            # NEW: wizard.report_footer2 = wizard.company_id.report_footer2
            wizard.paperformat_id = wizard.company_id.paperformat_id
            wizard.external_report_layout_id = wizard.company_id.external_report_layout_id
            wizard.font = wizard.company_id.font
            wizard.primary_color = wizard.company_id.primary_color
            wizard.secondary_color = wizard.company_id.secondary_color
            wizard_layout = wizard.env["report.layout"].search([
                ('view_id.key', '=', wizard.company_id.external_report_layout_id.key)
            ])
            wizard.report_layout_id = wizard_layout or wizard_layout.search([], limit=1)

            if not wizard.primary_color:
                wizard.primary_color = wizard.logo_primary_color or DEFAULT_PRIMARY
            if not wizard.secondary_color:
                wizard.secondary_color = wizard.logo_secondary_color or DEFAULT_SECONDARY
```

As you see I don t want to copy all into my module and just want to extend with super the 2 NEW lines. Can anyone help me how I can do that.
Kind regards

PS: I am new in this whole prgramming and stack overflow world sorry if my question may be confusing or even STUPID^^

Comment: The easy answer rename the method, and remove all code just keep your two lines it should work perfectly, you don't have to override the method because your not changing the original method logic, or just call super and after it afd the two lines of code it should work too

Comment: I don't get the downvote here, maybe there is a duplicate question, but the question itself is really ok. Maybe the downvoter can eloborate what the problem with this question is, so that it could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple. If you override a method, then you can call it with super() or super(YourClassName, self). Just check if overridden method returns anything.

```
    @api.onchange('company_id')
    def _onchange_company_id(self):
       result = super(YourClassName, self)._onchange_company_id()
       for wizard in self:
            wizard.report_footer1 = wizard.company_id.report_footer1
            wizard.report_footer2 = wizard.company_id.report_footer2
       return result
```